# Installing Sirius on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Can anybody please me how to install the Sirius, an open intelligent personal assistant on my Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit pc. 
link :  http://sirius.clarity-lab.org/ 
They say i have to compile it all and install it, but i get many compile errors in which many are very hard to find out. Please give some detailed instructions on the ways to easily compile this and run it on my pc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Make sure the system is up to date**

Run this following command one-by-one in terminal

```
sudo -s
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

**2. Install wget (abandon this if `wget` exist in your system)**

```
apt-get install wget
```

**3. Install sirius**

**NOTE: Sirius and its dependencies need several gigabyte, so make sure to allocate enough storage space.**

Install sirius from GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/jhauswald/sirius.git
cd sirius/sirius-application
tar xzf question-answer.tar.gz
```

Add extra repositories for ffmpeg

```
add-apt-repository ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
```

Enable multiverse sources for `libfaac-dev`

```
apt-add-repository multiverse
```

Update source

```
apt-get update
```

Install basic dependencies for Sirius

```
apt-get install git zip unzip subversion sox default-jdk ant automake autoconf libtool bison libboost-all-dev ffmpeg swig python-pip curl
```

Install `opencv` dependencies

```
apt-get install build-essential checkinstall git cmake libfaac-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore-dev texi2html yasm zlib1g-dev
```

Install tessaract text

```
apt-get install tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-eng libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev
```

Install protobuf

```
apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
```

Install dependencies for web apps

```
pip install wtforms Flask requests pickledb
```

**4. Install `opencv`**

Clone from GitHub

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git opencv-2.4.9
cd opencv-2.4.9
git checkout 2.4.9
```

Install Opencv on system

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make && make install && ldconfig -v
```

Prepare kaldi

```
cd ~/sirius/sirius-application/speech-recognition/kaldi/scripts
./prepare.sh
```

Arrange Sirius

```
 cd ~/sirius/sirius-application
./compile-sirius-servers.sh
```

**5. Running Sirius**

**A.** To open ASR server:

```
 cd ~/sirius/sirius-application/run-scripts
./start-asr-server.sh
```

Try use the pocketsphinx ASR

```
./start-asr-server.sh pocketsphinx
```

or specify an ASR, hostname and port

```
./start-asr-server.sh pocketsphinx localhost 8080
```

Open new terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run this following to test Sirius

```
./sirius-asr-test.sh ../inputs/questions/what.is.the.speed.of.light.wav
```

**B.** Image Matching (IMM)

Image Matching uses SURF to match query images to a stored database.

In image-matching/ first build and store a database of descriptors in protobuf format where the arguments are the name of the database and the directory containing the images

```
  cd ~/sirius/sirius-application/image-matching
 ./make-db.py landmarks matching/landmarks/db/
```

To change the database used by the IMM service, change the name in start-imm-server.py.

In run-scripts/, open the IMM server

```
cd ~/sirius/sirius-application/run-scripts
./start-imm-server.sh
```

Open new terminal window and test IMM

```
./sirius-imm-test.sh ../image-matching/matching/landmarks/query/query.jpg
```

**C.** Questing Answering System

The Question-Answering system uses OpenEphyra and a Wikipedia database stored in Lemur’s Indri format.

Extract the wikipedia database

```
cd ~/sirius/sirius-application
wget http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~jahausw/download/wiki_indri_index.tar.gz
tar xzvf wiki_indri_index.tar.gz -C question-answer/
```

Run the QA server

```
./start-qa-server.sh
```

Open new terminal and test QA

```
./sirius-qa-test.sh "what is the speed of light"
```

[**All credits goes to Sirius Official website**](http://sirius.clarity-lab.org/sirius/)

Comment: What about the sirius suite ?

Comment: Installation of sirius suite ? And have you successfully install sirius ?

Comment: yes i have been able to run these tests perfectly fine. what i want is the gui for this which is the sirius suite. Please help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks once again, but can you help me on installing the gui part? And do i have to download the Wikipedia database to the working of question and answer mode, can i do the search and answer me?

Comment: Yes you have to download wiki data base to make Q&A working, umm... I don't think Sirius has GUI (Graphical User Interface) application..